# Swift - Facebook chat bubbles: UITextView enable selection of the whole text view at one go, yet enable data detection

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uigesturerecognizer, uimenucontroller

Here's what I want to do:

Similar to Facebook's chat bubbles:

1. Tap on the whole chat cell, to bring up a `UIMenuController` displaying custom menu items (For now, just one copyAll item)
2. Preserve data detection and allow pressing on times, links, etc. **However, I want to disable pressing to highlight text.**
3. Single tap to show time below

I can only achieve 2 out of 3. 1) and 2) seem to always conflict.

Right now, I'm able to tap to show time below. I'm also able to preserve data detection, and show custom menu items. **However, because both showing custom menu item and data detection use the `LongPressGestureRecognizer`, sometimes the magnifying glass to highlight text will show up instead of my custom menu item.**

Here's my text view:

```
// Message text view in 
fileprivate lazy var messageTextView: CustomTextView = {
    var textView = CustomTextView()
    textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    textView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    textView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    textView.isEditable = false
    textView.isSelectable = true
    textView.tintColor = RED_UICOLOR
    textView.dataDetectorTypes = .all
    textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    textView.delegate = self

    // Long press to open custom menu controller
    let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(selectAllOfTextView))
    textView.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
    return textView

    // Tap to perform 3) show time below
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(notifyControllerToExpand))
    self.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}()
```

The long press calls this selector:

```
func selectAllOfTextView(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let loc = recognizer.location(in: self.messageTextView)
    // Pass recognizer press location over to the CustomTextView
    self.messageTextView.showMenu(location: loc)
}
```

And here's my `CustomTextView` class:

```
class CustomTextView: UITextView {

// Override the touches because I don't want any funky behavior from them
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    log.info("Touches began")
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    log.info("Touches moved")
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    log.info("Touches ended")
}

override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
    return true
}

override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if action == #selector(copyAll(_:)) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

// Function called by selector in the superclass
func showMenu(location: CGPoint) {
    self.becomeFirstResponder()
    let menuController = UIMenuController.shared
    let copyItem = UIMenuItem(title: "Copy", action: #selector(CustomTextView.copyAll(_:)))
    menuController.menuItems = [copyItem]
    let rect = CGRect(x: location.x - 35, y: self.frame.origin.y, width: 50, height: self.frame.height)
    menuController.setTargetRect(rect, in: self)
    menuController.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)
}

func copyAll(_ sender: Any?) {
    UIPasteboard.general.string = self.text
}
}
```

Comment: So it's like tap for an action, long press for another?

Comment: Exactly. But note that I still want to preserve the default long press of textView (that comes when isSelectable = true) so that I can click on links. But I don't want the long press that highlights text.